What does \token_if_expandable:N(TF) actually test?
In LaTeX3 am wondering what \token_if_expandable:N(TF) actually test? The documentation says:

Tests if the ⟨token⟩ is expandable. This test returns ⟨false⟩ for an
undefined token.

but I am guessing that it's a little bit more complicated than that.

Have a look in l3token.dtx, there is the implementtion and the code above explains how it works. I would not have guessed that that was how it worked, so yes it is a little complicated, but very short code.

For a typeset version of l3token.dtx (and all the other l3*.dtx files) take a look at source3.pdf.

It tests whether the token is altered by \exp_not:N (expandable tokens are temporarily turned into \relax by it), and whether the token is a defined control sequence using the \ifdefined primitive.
The actual code looks like this:
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \token_if_expandable:N #1 {TF, T, F, p}
  {
    \exp_after:wN \if_meaning:w \exp_not:N #1#1
      \prg_return_false:
    \else:
      \if_cs_exist:N #1
        \prg_return_true:
      \else:
        \prg_return_false:
      \fi:
    \fi:
  }


so if it isn't affected by \exp_not:N or it isn't a control sequence, return not-expandable?

@cfr correct :)

I use classical TeX terminology here. The main point is in the construction \expandafter\ifx\noexpand\sequence\sequence. The \noexpand expandable primitive puts to the following \sequence the temporary meaning \relax if it is expandable \sequence. Otherwise it does nothing. Then \ifx compares the meaning of "touched" \sequence and the following \sequence.
The macro for testing this can look like this:
\def\return#1{\csname if#1\expandafter\endcsname\romannumeral}
\def\expandtest#1\iftrue{%
   \ifdefined#1%
      \expandafter\ifx\noexpand#1#1\return{false}% <<- the main point is here
      \else \return{true}%
      \fi
   \else \return{false}%
   \fi 0
}

\def\what#1{\string#1 is \expandtest#1\iftrue expandable\else unexpandable\fi\par}

                 % prints:
\what\hbox       %  \hbox is unexpandable
\what\the        %  \the is expandable
\what\TeX        %  \TeX is expandable 
\what\undefined  %  \undefined is unexpandable
\what A          %  A is unexpandable
\what ~          %  ~ is expandable
\what \relax     % \relax is unexpandable

\bye

